# E2EE Javascript/NodeJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

So I'm currently working on implementing end-to-end encryption and would like to encrypt data client side before sending to the server to be stored. This would also be vice-versa so data would be send from the server after being requested and it would be decrypted at client side.

This is going being a pretty basic, but wanted to provide an example.

For example, the user sends a message and we want to encrypt it before sending it off to server side.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type your message here...">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="update()">
</form>

<script>
    function update() {
        var data = document.getElementById("message").value;
        // Assuming we have an encrypt function, presumably aes256-cfb
        document.getElementById("message").value = encrypt(data);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Then for the server side

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['message'];
$pdo->query("insert into messages (message) values (`$data`)");
// etc...
```

Would a method like this be suitable, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: yeah that's how you would do it. I'm assuming that the client would have access to the secret key only? and it's not transmitted anywhere and is lost when the user ends there current session.

Answer (score -1):

It's recommended you do the encryption on the server side - especially from a browser. POST the forum over HTTPS and let the server encrypt the plaintext data. Never trust the client!

Also as a quick tip, you have a SQL injection waiting to happen with the PHP database query. Change the to use a prepared statement like this:

```
<?php
$query = $pdo->prepare('insert into messages (message) values (:message)');
$query->execute(array(
    'message' => $_POST['message']
));
```

Comment: So, I'm trying to do end-to-end encryption (E2EE) which protects data so it can only be read on the two ends, the sender and the recipient. Thus why it's being encrypted client side and not server side.

The PHP database query was an example to use purely to see if it worked, in a production environment, it would be much more complicated.

Comment: Regarding encryption of client data, the right paradigm in this case is to never trust the server.